# Using Boost Spirit to parse a text file while skipping large parts of it

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, seek

I have the following `std::string`:

```
<lots of text not including "label A" or "label B">    
label A: 34
<lots of text not including "label A" or "label B">
label B: 45
<lots of text not including "label A" or "label B">
...
```

I want extract single integral numbers following all occurrences of `label A` or `label B` and place them in corresponding `vector<int> a, b`. A simple, but not elegant way of doing it is using `find("label A")` and `find("label B")` and parsing whichever is first. Is there a succinct way of expressing it using Spirit? How do you skip everything but `label A` or `label B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just

```
omit [ eol >> *char_ - ("\nlabel A:") ] >> eol
```

Example: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/417cfb7a198e9ede)**

There's also the `seek[]` directive in the repository. The following is equivalent to the above:

```
 repo::seek [ eol >> &lit("int main") ]
```

Here's a sample that parses your original sample:

```
*repo::seek [ eol >> "label" >> char_("A-Z") >> ':' >> int_ ],
```

This will parse into `std::vector<std::pair<char, int> >` without anything else.

**[On Coliru Too](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/359a176fcd88bbd8)**:

```
#if 0
<lots of text not including "label A" or "label B">    
label A: 34
<lots of text not including "label A" or "label B">
label B: 45
<lots of text not including "label A" or "label B">
...
#endif
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>
#include <fstream>

namespace qi   = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace repo = boost::spirit::repository::qi;

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("main.cpp");
    ifs >> std::noskipws;

    boost::spirit::istream_iterator f(ifs), l;

    std::vector<std::pair<char, int> > parsed;
    using namespace qi;
    bool ok = phrase_parse(
            f, l, 
            *repo::seek [ eol >> "label" >> char_("A-Z") >> ':' >> int_ ],
            blank,
            parsed
        );

    if (ok)
    {
        std::cout << "Found:\n";
        for (auto& p : parsed)
            std::cout << "'" << p.first << "' has value " << p.second << "\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Fail at: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Notes:

- `seek` does expose the attribute matched, which is pretty powerful:

  ```
  repo::seek [ eol >> "label" >> char_("ABCD") >> ':' ]
  ```

  will 'eat' the label, but expose the label letter (`'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, or `'D'`) as the attribute.
- Performance when skipping can be pretty surprising, read the warning in the documentation http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/seek.html

Output is

```
Found:
'A' has value 34
'B' has value 45
```

Comment: I've edited to show the `seek` directive on your actual sample data.